# Subir archivos PDF a Buckets S3 en AWS renombrándolos a un nombre estándar

Tags: php, aws

Estoy haciendo una pagina simple para subir archivos PDF a unos buckets en AWS, este codigo permite que nosotros escojamos el archivo (con extension PDF) para subirlo, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que ese archivo cambie a un nombre ya definido, por ejemplo si subo el archivo "mensaje.pdf" al subirlo se renombre automáticamente a "informe.pdf" y asi para cualquier archivo PDF

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];   
        $temp_file_location = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 

        require 'vendor/autoload.php';

        $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'region'  => 'us-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => "access_key",
                'secret' => "secret_key",
            ]
        ]);     

        $result = $s3->putObject([
            'Bucket' => 'bucketPrueba',
            // Se añade a la key la ubicación donde necesitemos guardar el archivo segun el arbol de carpetas en el bucket
            // Cambiar el nombre de los archivo
//          'Key'    => 'Contenido/'.$file_name,
            'Key'    => $file_name,
            'SourceFile' => $temp_file_location         
        ]);
        
        // Imprime el resultado de la ejecucion de subida de archivo

        // var_dump($result);
    }
?>

<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">         
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Renombra el archivo localmente antes de subirlo al S3

Comment: osea si, pero la cuestión es que esta pequeña aplicación lo que debería evitar es justamente esa corta tarea de cambiar el nombre localmente, a lo mejor hay alguna forma de cambiar el nombre mientras esta subido en cache o archivos temporales me imagino pero no se como hacerlo si es que se pudiera

Comment: Pues `$temp_file_location` tiene la ruta completa del archivo y pareciera que `$file_name` puede llevar el nombre que tendrá el archivo (que tú le pongas el mismo nombre que tenía al cargarse, es otra cosa). Prueba poniéndole otro nombre en ese $file_name, pepito.txt